T-SQL query to get computer name that has not made a query to database in 60 days
I have a table Queries that keeps track of every query made to a database with a date_time stamp and the computer name.
There can be 1000s of rows for the same computer, each one with a different date_time stamp.
If the computer has not made a query in 60 days, then it needs to be identified.
I know how to check each record to see if it has been longer than 60 days for that specific query record.
I do not know how to consider all the records for that specific computer to determine if the SMALLEST date_time stamp is greater than 60 days and if so, to show it in the results.
Please forgive as I am new to SQL queries. Thanks.
I tried:
select computer_name 
from queries 
where date_time > 20240508000000

I only want to show a computer_name IF it does not have a single record that is less than 60 days old - because that means it has not been used for a query in 2 months and needs to be identified.
The above example is wrong in that it will show ALL records that are greater than 60 days.

Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Do you have a separate list of all machines? Why are you storing dates as integers?

Without testing, and assuming the timestamp is in data-type datetime or similar, I suggest this. The idea is to get the youngest timestamp for every computer by use of group by (aggregation), and then filter for those whose youngest-timestamp is more than 60 days old compared to now (GETDATE()).
After additional information became available I updated the solution. I do not know the data type that produces values like 202407080000US or 20240508000000, so i use a rather crude way to convert to data type DATE, ignoring time parts. I also don't know, which part of this input is month and which is day, so check that.
;WITH prep AS(
SELECT
  computer_name
  ,date = CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), date_time), 8))
FROM queries
)
SELECT
  computer_name
  ,youngest = MAX(date)
FROM prep
GROUP BY computer_name
HAVING MAX(date) <= DATEADD(DAY, -60, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
-- This works, too, but it is better to keep 
-- the column as much as possible outside of functions:
--HAVING DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(date), CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) > 60


Adding an index on queries(computer_name, date_time) can increase performance, if you find that your query runs slower than desired.

@TN - For a GROUP BY computer_name query SQL Server won't take any advantage of date_time being the second key column in the index when finding the MAX - if you want that kind of plan you need to do an effective TOP 1 query for each computer_name (sub query, apply, recursive CTE)

@ Der U - The following error is received:
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Also, I failed to mention that the data/time is like 202407080000US.

I modified the answer just now. Could You elaborate on the data type of date_time? Where is it from? What software? Other RDBMS?

@MartinSmith - Good point. Looks like I assumed an index optimization that isn't implemented. Best I could get was an index scan. (fiddle). However, if the table contains contains other "wide" columns like query-text, the "narrow" index might still reduce reads.

Instead of converting every date-text value, you could define and apply a date-text limit with something like: DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()),
DECLARE @CutoffText VARCHAR(50) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @CutoffDate, 112) + '000000', and then the original answer modified with HAVING MAX(date_time) < @CutoffDate. Full query:
SELECT computer_name, youngest = MAX(date_time) FROM queries GROUP BY computer_name HAVING MAX(date_time) < @CutoffDate.

@ Der U - It might work, but I am not sure how to specify the table Queries in the complex statement.  If I put a From in the first select, it gives error that Incorrect syntax near 'from' even though the columns names resolve.  If I remove that and put queries.date_time, then an error occurs that The multi part identifier could not be bound.  But I think it is almost there!

@ Der U - date_time is varchar(16)
I am not sure of the source software, just querying database with SSMS to an SQL server.

@colemd1 Firstly, I screwed up and forgot the FROM clause in the cte, I hope I finally got this edited into runable. Secondly, depending on the environment You run this in You may need to omit the semicolon at the beginning. Please try again.

@ Der U - YOU ARE THE MAN!!!  Thanks, it works.

@colemd1 Glad to help. Still would like to know where You got these values from. varchar(16) just means that sql server stores it as string. This format may give You issues, particularly when the time part becomes relevant. Why does it sometimes give You two zeroes and sometimes 'US' for the last two positions? You should check what's goin' on there.
